# What is the env value in if condition of ant script

Tags: ant

Can someone tell from where the build script is taking $env variable value?. Dont find anything in the ant build script.

```
    <if>
        <or>
            <equals arg1="${env}" arg2="test"/>
            <equals arg1="${env}" arg2="dev"/>
        </or>
        <then>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the script is designed to run with additional properties. From the command line for example, like:

```
ant -Denv=test
```